# Is it possible to configure two way ssl on LDAP between WAS7 and ActiveDirectory

Tags: ssl, active-directory, ldap, websphere-7

Is it possible to configure LDAP over two sided SSL between IBM WebSphere Application Server and MS ActiveDirectory? I can not find any confirmation, it is possible or not to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the ActiveDirectory part but for the WebSphere part:

When you add the repository to check `Require SSL communications`, then you select `Use specific ssl configuration`

When you click `SSL configurations` you can create a new configuration and provide both server and client certificates there.

Once you do that it should do two sided SSL verification.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do I understand correctly that if a AD will require the use of two-way ssl it is enough that the required certificates are added to ssl configuration?

Comment: If it requires then You need to retrieve the AD certificates to WAS and also export the certificates from WAS to AD